# Deep linking in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, deep-linking

Silverlight supports deep linking in the latest version.  Does JavaFX?

Comment: I am looking for the same answers right now.

Answer (score 0):

Answering with a non-answer because there hasn't been any yet...

I have not seen any references to deep linking in JavaFX.

Because I couldn't find any references to deep linking in JavaFX, I was curious as to whether or not JavaFX web apps even had access to URL parameters when loaded in a web page. Surprisingly, I couldn't find any references to this either. I'm still not ready to believe that JavaFX apps can't access URL parameters. I hope I just wasn't searching long enough, because that would be a huge disadvantage to the language if it's true.